# Setting spines in matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a strange reason I cannot find the way to specify spines configuration in Python's matplotlibrc file. Any idea on how to cause matplotlib not to draw upper and right spines by default?
[image: spines]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_images/whats_new_99_spines.png))</sub>

More about info about spines in matplotlib is [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#axis-spine-placement)

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to hide the right and top spines of a subplot, you need to both set the colour of the relevant spines to `'none'`, as well as set the tick position to `'left'` for the xtick, and `'bottom'` for the ytick (in order to hide the tick marks as well as the spines).

Unfortunately, none of these are currently accessible via `matplotlibrc`. The parameters specified in `matplotlibrc` are validated, and then stored in a dict called `rcParams`. It is then up to the individual modules to check for a key in this dict whose value will act as their default. If they don't check it for one of their options, that option is not alterable via the `rc` file.

Due to the nature of the `rc` system, and the way that spines are written, altering the code to allow for this would not be straightforward:

Spines currently obtain their colour through the same `rc` parameter used to define axis colours; you cannot set it to `'none'` without hiding all of your axis drawing. They are also agnostic towards whether they are `top`, `right`, `left`, or `bottom` — these are really just four separate spines stored in a dict. The individual spine objects do not know what side of the plot they compose, so you cannot just add new `rc` params and assign the proper one during spine initialization.

```
self.set_edgecolor( rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] )
```

(*./matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/spines.py*, __init__(), *line 54*)

If you have a large amount of existing code, such that adding the axis parameters manually to each one would be too burdensome, you could alternately use a helper function to iterate through all of the Axis objects and set the values for you.

Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import show

# Set up a default, sample figure. 
fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
y = 2*np.sin(x)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_title('Normal Spines')

def hide_spines():
    """Hides the top and rightmost axis spines from view for all active
    figures and their respective axes."""

    # Retrieve a list of all current figures.
    figures = [x for x in matplotlib._pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_all_fig_managers()]
    for figure in figures:
        # Get all Axis instances related to the figure.
        for ax in figure.canvas.figure.get_axes():
            # Disable spines.
            ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
            ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
            # Disable ticks.
            ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

hide_spines()
show()
```

Just call `hide_spines()` before `show()`, and it will hide them in all of the figures that `show()` displays. I cannot think of a simpler way to alter a large number of figures, outside of spending the time to patch `matplotlib` and add in `rc` support for the needed options.

Answer (score 17):

To make matplotlib not to draw upper and right spines, one can set the following in matplotlibrc file

```
axes.spines.right : False
axes.spines.top : False
```

Comment: Can you also remove the ticks from the top and right axes from the matplotlibrc file?

Comment: @jkokorian:  In the coming 2.0.0 release of matplotlib, you can set the `xtick.top` and `ytick.right` options.

Answer (score 0):

```
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)    
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
```