# Default matplotlib spines colors for custom style

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, configuration-files

I want to create a custom style for matplotlib. I saved this file in a local folder `libstyle/my_style.mplstyle`. The current content of the file is:

```
### AXES
axes.grid: True
axes.autolimit_mode: round_numbers

### FONT
font.family: sans-serif
font.sans-serif: Arial
```

where I setup font, grid and axes limits. I plan to use this style with the call:

```
plt.style.use(r'libstyle/my_style.mplstyle')
```

I would like to set a default color for each of the four spines like in the image:

[image]

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059429/9214357), I already know I can add to any python script these lines:

```
ax.spines['top'].set_color('red')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('blue')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('green')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('orange')
```

But I would like to move all *aesthetic* configuration from python scripts to `my_style.mplstyle` file.
The point is that I don't know which parameter in `my_style.mplstyle` I have to edit in order to specify the color of a single spine. I followed this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), but didn't find anything about spines color.
Is there a way to set up spines color (one color for each of the four spines) in a `.mplstyle`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to set the color of individual spines in a style sheet (you can set all through `axes.edgecolor`). [See this SO answer for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3509553/2694260).