# Is it possible to put bbox_to_anchor into a matplotlibrc file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

- I would like to define a standard matplotlib style using a matplotlibrc file, with the plot legend outside the plot. This is possible using bbox_to_anchor in the plot code, but this is not a known rcparam. Any other options?
- Is it possible to make all plot titles appear in capitals using matplotlibrc?

Comment: The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439344/setting-spines-in-matplotlibrc) seems useful for figuring out what can be controlled by matplotlibrc and what can't. I haven't checked for bbox_to_anchor and uppercasing, though.

Comment: If the answer without bbox_to_anchor was useful, this question might be more useful with a different title. "Automatically plot with a legend outside the plot"? "Enforcing plot styles without rcParams"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that neither of those things can be set in rcParams. You can get the sidebar-legend by passing a tuple as the `loc` argument to `legend()`, but rcParams can't handle tuple values yet. And I don't think rcParams is the right place to do text modification like uppercasing.

You can put both into a decorator, along with rcParams, and have a decorated version of pyplot calls:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

xs, x2s, ys = [4,1,3,5,2], [1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,1,2,-1]

def house_style(func):
    def sidelegend_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        title = kwargs.pop('title', None)
        with plt.style.context('dark_background'): #or your rcParams
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            cf = plt.gcf()
            cf.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)
            cax = plt.gca()
            if title: cax.set_title(title.upper())
            cax.legend(loc=(1.1, .8))
    return(sidelegend_wrapper)

@house_style
def decorated_scatter(*args, **kwargs):
    plt.scatter(*args, **kwargs)

@house_style
def decorated_plot(*args, **kwargs):
    plt.plot(*args, **kwargs)
    
decorated_scatter(xs, ys, label='decorator', title='lowercase')
decorated_plot(x2s, ys, label='also dec')
```

Result:

[image: Plot with dark background from rcParam stylesheet, side legend from decorator]

If I needed to plot into specific axes instead of using `pyplot` I would put that *and* what just went into the decorator into a function:

```
def our_function(*args, **kwargs):
    title = kwargs.pop('title', None)
    sc_data = kwargs.pop('sc_data', None)
    line_data = kwargs.pop('line_data', None)
    fig, axs= plt.subplots(2)
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)
    axs[0].scatter(sc_data[0],sc_data[1], **kwargs)
    axs[1].plot(line_data[0], line_data[1], **kwargs)
    if title: fig.suptitle(title.upper())
    axs[0].legend(loc=(1.1,.5))

  

our_function(sc_data = [xs, ys], line_data=[x2s, ys], label='function', title='lowercase\nwell, it was')

plt.show()
```

[image: two-axes plot with capitalized title and side legend]

That one doesn't call rcParams but could, just like the decorators.

Possibly one could decorate the `Axes` class itself so that every instance had decorated plotting functions?